# Understanding the graph of $\max \{ |x + \frac{1}{4}| , |x^{2}| \} < 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\max \{ |x + \tfrac{1}{4}| , |x^{2}| \} < 1$$

I visualized the graph in Wolfram Alpha and it says that the solution is $-1 < x < \frac{3}{4}$, but after the solution of the exercise it's the interval of $-1 < x < \frac{1}{2} $.

Is it $-1 < x < \frac{1}{2} $ really the correct solution? If it's correct, than why?

Comment: The right solution is $-1 < x < \frac{3}{4}.$ Plot both in the same coordinate system.

Comment: You probably did a mistake. For $x>0,$ the maximum is $|x+\frac{1}{4}|.$ Solve $x+\frac{1}{4}<1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the solution of the exercise provide steps? If not, here is an algebraic method that analyses the inequality and geometry:

$|x + \frac{1}{4}| = x^2$ has **minimum** $2$ solutions near $x = 0$ as both are concave up graphs with different gradients, along with the hint that $|x| > x^2, |x| < 1$. There is **at least** one positive and one negative solution.

$|x + \frac{1}{4}| \begin{cases} x + \frac{1}{4} \quad, & x \ge\frac{-1}{4} \\ -x - \frac{1}{4} \quad, & x \le \frac{-1}{4}\end{cases}$

$|x^2| = x^2$.

Hence, for $x \ge\frac{-1}{4}$ : $$x^2 = x + \frac{1}{4} \\ x^2 - x - \frac{1}{4} = 0 \\ x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{2}}{2} \to x = \frac{1 \color{red}{+} \sqrt{2}}{2}$$

And $x \le \frac{-1}{4}$ : $$x^2 = -x - \frac{1}{4} \\ x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} = 0 \\ x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-1}}{2} = \frac{-1}{2}$$

From the positive section, $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{2}$, we see that  $|x + \frac{1}{4}|$ is greater for $y = 1$, $\left(1 < \frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$.

From the negative section, $x = \frac{-1}{2}$, we see that  $|x^2|$ is greater at $y= 1$. The second negative solution does not play a role here, since we looking for the largest domain of solutions.

Finally, the respective positive and negative bounds, $x + \frac{1}{4} = 1, x = \frac{3}{4} \\ x^2 = 1, x = -1$

giving

$$-1 < x < \frac{3}{4}$$